# Access drop location via server in TFS releases

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

TFS 2015 update 2, release management framework. In server definition, there's a flag whether this server should access the drop location via straight UNC, or via HTTP(S) to the Release Management Server (RMS). Question: which builtin actions/tools are aware of this setting? The "XCopy Deployer" tool, and "Copy File or Folder" action, which is based on it, definitely don't respect that setting - it just tries to xcopy straight from the source UNC path.

The only UI that mentions drop location is the custom component creation UI.

Answer (score 0):

All of the built-in actions work with this setting. So do custom deployment tools, for that matter.

The way it works is as follows:

The normal behavior (directly from UNC) has the Agent reach out to the drop location directly in order to stage the files in a temporary location on the machine on which the agent runs. This folder is usually `C:\users\<service account>\AppData\Local\Temp\RM\T\RM\` if I'm not mistaken. After that, it runs the deployment activity against the staged files.

The other option (via HTTP) has the RM server reach out to the UNC path, then serialize the files over HTTP to the agent machine. After that, it runs the deployment activity against the staged files.

Basically, all that flag does is change the behavior of how the files get to the target box. It doesn't change the behavior of the commands that are invoked.

However, it's entirely possible that the UNC vs HTTP option is ignored when using a component that points directly to a UNC path; that behavior I haven't tested.

Since you're using TFS 2015.2, you should look into retiring your Release Management server and migrating to the new web-based experience. The ALM Rangers have a [migration tool](https://github.com/ALM-Rangers/Migrate-assets-from-RM-server-to-VSTS/releases) available.

Comment: "the UNC vs HTTP option is ignored when using a component that points directly to a UNC path" is exactly the case, as far as I can see. Putting together a custom component over xcopy, however, does the trick. The local copy of the drop location becomes the current folder of the tool.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please confirm one thing:
When you use the option “Through Release Management Server over HTTP(S)” it’s important that the Service account were RM is installed with has modify rights on the drop location. 
if you want to use Server option, this is something by design:

1. With agent based flow, we don’t support “build drop on server” and “drop via HTTP on RM” together.
2. If you want to have these options, then you can use vNext workflow which will support both.

It ideally should work with xcopy.

Please drop me an email atdmittal@microsoft.com if things still does not work...

Comment: I don't use auto builds. The drop location is populated elsewhere. I kind of found a workaround with a custom component over the Xcopy deploy tool.